# Where deploy config file and exe files?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, deployment, compact-framework, windows-ce

My question is pretty simple, I've a device running on WinCE. This device as an additional Flash Disk device, so where should I deploy the config and exe files? On Flash Disk or in %PROGRAM FILES% ?

Moreover, I've a XML setting file added as "New Element", so it appears in the Properties section (see screenshot), how can I deploy this file on my device (by specifying the path?)

[image: servers.xml]

Should I use a resource file instead? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application is a .Net application you can put it where you want as the apps can be deployed with xcopy, it's just a matter of taste.

If you want to deploy the file select it, go to properties and select "Copy to Output always"

Comment: Considering Flash Disk as a storage space, read operations are faster on it and more secure, no? How can I specify the deployment path?

Comment: Well, probably both locations will be a flash disk, one external and the other one soldered to the board so it really does not matter.

Comment: About deploying the application you can read this entry witch has all the required information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446503.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a cab file if you want to deploy it permanently. You can find documentation on it in MSDN. There you can set the path to where ever you want.